# how can I extract picture from Open3d?

Tags: python, visualization, open3d

I have .ply pointcloud, where z coordinate is 0 (so, it is 2D, actually). How can I get and save .jpg or .png image of my PCD using open3D? I need something like plan of my PCD x-y projection with a chance to download it and save.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import open3d as o3d

pcd_full = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("data/single_precision/pcd_full.ply")
pcd_full.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])

vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window()
vis.add_geometry(pcd_full)
vis.update_geometry(pcd_full)
vis.poll_events()
vis.update_renderer()
vis.capture_screen_image("data/save_visualization/1.jpg")
vis.destroy_window()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful, of better quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.