# open3d OffscreenRenderer EGL Headless is not supported on this platform error on Windows

Tags: windows, rendering, open3d

I am trying to run this simple python code on windows:

```
import open3d as o3d
render = o3d.visualization.rendering.OffscreenRenderer(640, 480)
```

and getting this error:
EGL Headless is not supported on this platform

I am using:
open3d 0.17.0
python 3.8.3
Windows 11

Tried running this simple example but couldn't find a solution on windows and open3d 0.17.0

Comment: AFAIK, offscreen renderer is not supported on Windows. See official reply from erissa as well - https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/6423#issuecomment-1761700719

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599095/how-can-i-extract-picture-from-open3d and http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/geometry/ray_casting.html for alternative approaches.